# Entity Framework Core sum with sub-queries throws Invalid Operation Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.1

I have the following line of code to calculate a total cost.

```
var results = dbContext.Logs.Select(x => new
        {
            Cost = x.Rows.Sum(y => x.Rows.SelectMany(z => z.Organisation.UserRoleRates).Single(z => z.OrganisationId == y.OrganisationId && z.UserRoleId == y.Log.User.UserRole.Id).CostPerHour * y.DurationHours)
        }).ToList();
```

When this gets executed an exception is thrown with the following message

> InvalidOperationException: variable 'x' of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueBuffer' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

If I change to code to make a call to `ToList()` straight away (avoiding EF executing the expression) it works as expected.

```
var results = dbContext.Logs.ToList().Select(x => new
        {
            Cost = x.Rows.Sum(y => x.Rows.SelectMany(z => z.Organisation.UserRoleRates).Single(z => z.OrganisationId == y.OrganisationId && z.UserRoleId == y.Log.User.UserRole.Id).CostPerHour * y.DurationHours)
        }).ToList();
```

Is it possible to get the expression working with Entity Framework Core?

Comment: The error message is pretty odd and doesn't seem directly related to your linq expression. Did you tried just changing the alias (here: `x`)?

Comment: And btw. `.Select` on "List" is something completely different than `.Select` on an IQueryable. The former one is an action lambda (using anonymous methods), the later one is an expression. Both use the lambda syntax, but one (anonymous method) is executable code, an expression is only meta data which **describes** code. expression can be executed/evaluated. It needs to be compiled to an Action/Func before it can be executed/evaluated

Comment: If I change the name of the variable I get the same exception, just with the new variable name instead of 'x'.

Comment: Which DB Provider? (They are the one who translates the expression into SQL)

Comment: I'm using the SQL Server provider

Comment: Apparently this is EF Core internal bug. But the expression `x.Rows` inside `x.Rows.Sum(...)` is quite unusual, which probably confuses EF Core query translator. What actually are you trying to achieve with that query?

Comment: Ah okay, I appreciate the query is rather odd. Essentially I'd like to order the retrieved data set by the result of calculation a rate of pay by number of hours worked (these are stored across different tables), since there is also a paging mechanism I was trying to have this performed database side.